# Catch the point when a GEF editor is ready for user interaction

Tags: eclipse, listener, eclipse-gef

*Disclaimer: Cross-posted on the Eclipse GEF forum. Will delete over there once the question has been answered here, or provide answer from there.*

Is there any way to catch the point when the editor is "ready" after opening it?

By "ready" I mean that all `EditPart`s have been created and all figures are shown. I.e., the editor is ready for editing.

I'd like to be able to hook in at that point and perform some calculations on coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Add a org.eclipse.draw2d.LayoutListener to the contents top figure (the diagram figure, child of the root figure). Once #postLayout(IFigure) is called you're safe to assume that everything is laid out and ready.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for cases where I don't have a lot of figures. However, when drawing a larger number of figures, `postLayout()` is called before the figures are visible in the editor (tried by a simple sys out message, which appears seconds before the figures are shown). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Having read up a bit more on the problem, I've found that child figures are validated top-down, that is, the top figure in the editor will only validate its children once it's been layouted itself, hence there is a delay between calling `postLayout()` and having all figures shown in the editor.